# Changing which drive the boot sector is on

Tags: windows-7, grub, bootsector

I ordered a pre-built computer from a custom computer manufacturer, but asked them to install an SSD and make it the primary drive (C:), with the hard drive that was formerly the primary drive to be used only for storage (E:).

However, the boot sector appears to still be on E:, and it seems to be causing a few minor issues with booting and creating system images. Is there any way that I can clone the boot sector to C:? Note too that I've installed Linux and hence GRUB (which only boots if E: is set above C: in the boot order), which might complicate things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot into Linux, install Grub on to the MBR of the SSD and you're done.

You don't have to change anything else because Grub can find its configuration files automatically. However you most likely have to perform the installation manually through command line. The commands are different for Grub very-close-to-2.0 and older versions, so you'll have to find some tutorial online for your version. But I guess the harder work will be guessing the device file of the SSD (or not).